# Is there a way that Fury was not himself since the beginning of the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home, nick-fury

As we know from the post credit scene of *Spider-Man: Far From Home*

> Fury is not Fury but Talos the Skrull from *Captain Marvel* impersonated Fury.

Is there any clue in all the MCU that could tell us that Fury was impersonated since the beginning? And by "beginning", I mean for every movie which took place after the event of *Captain Marvel*.

I think for example of the scene in *Captain America: Winter Soldier*, when Fury uses a second eye to unlock the S.H.I.E.L.D files.

> Could it be Talos impersonated another important eye?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yeah I think it is :( Even if the answer there doesn't suit me :) *Case closed ! But still open... until I solved it*

Comment: I have expanded on my answer slightly there but at the moment we don't have any more information on this. It is one of those things that is most certainly going to be addressed in Phase 4.

Comment: Ah ah, good thinking the diagonal toast. I was looking for more clue that could explain the Talos presence. Maybe I could edit my question to fit better this research ?

Comment: To be honest the clues for each are going to be the same... you might be able to sufficiently word this to be different but the answer would be pretty much identical at the moment.

Comment: Ok thanks ^.^ I confirm the duplicate

Comment: @TinyDoowy go see my comment on the original question  I literally said the same thing